# Changes to biblatex-mla8 \autocite*-command

Tags: biblatex, mla-style, biblatex-mla

For a project I'm following the MLA rules in their 8th edition for citations and there's a problem I can't solve. I'm using `biblatex-mla-new` (which is, I think, still beta?) by James Clawson, which is really good except for some small issues I'm having.

Whenever I'm using an author's name in the written text, I only have to give page numbers in in-text citations (in brackets). In case there's more than one title for one author, I have to add a title - this is being done by using `\autocite*`. If I don't mention the author's name in the text, it has to go into the brackets as well, using `\autocite` (without the asterisk). It all works fine as long as the entry has a title - but not when there is no title, which is the case for, e.g., introductions. To follow the MLA rules, I use the field `titleaddon = {Introduction}`, which results in a proper entry in the bibliography itself, but neither `\autocite` nor `\autocite*` use it, therefore, the entry within the brackets is always missing this crucial bit of information. I have accomplished to achieve the desired result for `\autocite` (cf. mwe), but I have no idea where to look at for `\autocite*`...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=mla-new,nofullfootnote]{biblatex}

%--changes to lines 173-187 of mla-new.cbx
\renewbibmacro*{cite:mla:title:internal}{%
    \ifbool{cbx@named}{\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}{}%
    \iffieldundef{title}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{review}%
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]%
            {\printtext{\bibcpstring{reviewof}%
                    \setunit{\addspace}%
                    \printfield{booktitle}}}}%
        {\printfield{titleaddon}}}% -->this line replaces lines 181-185 of mla8.cbx
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
            \printfield[citetitle:\strfield{entrytype}]{labeltitle}}}}%

%!!!----!!!
%--the following changes to my mind improve a couple of things in biblatex-mla-new which I noticed while working with my bibliographic entries

%--title and/or subtitle of collections do not stand in if incollections don't have a title/subtitle of their own; instead, titleaddon is used (in case of, e.g., untitled introductions)

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{title}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
    }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
            \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
            \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
            \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
        \newunit}%
    \printfield{titleaddon}\addperiod\space}

%--to put the period at the end of the title within the inverted commas

\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\addperiod}}

%--changing the way dates are written (ordinal numbers become cardinal numbers in, e.g., dates of last access for websites)

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
    \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
        \iffieldundef{#3}
        {}
        {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
            \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
        \iffieldundef{#2}
        {}
        {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
            \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
        \stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
}

%--IMPORTANT!!! I also needed to make a change directly to mla-new.bbx, replace \newunit with \newblockpunct in line 398 (within \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}; cf. entry for Jason Donald, which ends with a comma instead of with a period in the bibliography without the change - so far, I haven't noticed any unwanted behaviour and copying all the relevant lines into my preamble was rather too much). 

%!!!----!!!

\addbibresource{katrinbiblio.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{katrinbiblio.bib}
@collection{Anker.2017,
    year = {2017},
    title = {New Directions in Law and Literature},
    publisher = {{Oxford UP}},
    editor = {Anker, Elizabeth S. and Meyler, Bernadette},
    location = {New York}
}
@incollection{Anker.2017b,
    author = {Anker, Elizabeth S. and Meyler, Bernadette},
    pages = {1--30},
    publisher = {{Oxford UP}},
    editor = {Anker, Elizabeth S. and Meyler, Bernadette},
    booktitle = {New Directions in Law and Literature},
    titleaddon = {Introduction},
    year = {2017},
    location = {New York}
}
@book{Donald.2018,
    author = {Donald, Jason},
    year = {2018},
    title = {Dalila},
    publisher = {Vintage},
    isbn = {1784702986},
    location = {London},
    abstract = {}
}
@article{Posner.1986,
    author = {Posner, Richard A.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {Law and Literature},
    pages = {1351--1392},
    volume = {72},
    journaltitle = {Virginia Law Review},
    subtitle = {A Relation Reargued},
    number = {8},
    shorttitle = {Relation Reargued}
}
@book{Posner.2009,
    author = {Posner, Richard A.},
    year = {2009},
    title = {Law and Literature},
    edition = {3},
    publisher = {{Harvard UP}},
    location = {Cambridge}
}
@incollection{Stern.2017,
    author = {Stern, Simon},
    title = {Legal and Literary Fictions},
    pages = {313--326},
    publisher = {{Oxford UP}},
    editor = {Anker, Elizabeth S. and Meyler, Bernadette},
    booktitle = {New Directions in Law and Literature},
    year = {2017},
    location = {New York}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

As Anker and Meyler state, the situation is diverse \autocite*[2]{Anker.2017b}. They go even further and present more diversity \autocite[3]{Anker.2017b}. Posner, on the other hand, is a real pessimist \autocite*[2]{Posner.2009}. He has been that all through his career \autocite[3]{Posner.1986}. Still, the others respect him \autocite[1]{Anker.2017b}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What's between `%!!!----!!!` is not relevant for my problem but are changes which to my mind improve the mla-new-style - I provided them in case someone is coming across this thread searching for a solution.

Is there anyone out there who can help me make changes to \autocite*, as I seem unable to find where this command is set...

Comment: I'm so sorry, I don't seem to be able to add "Dear all" in the beginning...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You neither need to add a greeting nor a thanks at the end. It is normally preferred to leave them out so the question can focus on the important bits.

Comment: Where did you get `mla8`? https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-mla and https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla only have `mla` and `mla-new`?

Comment: Sorry! Due to the changes I made to the .bbx-file, I created a new name not to get confused - but it seems I did confuse the two: mla8 is my changed version, mla-new the original one!

Comment: That is *exactly* the right way to do things. But we may assume `mla-new`, right? The only change between your `mla8` and `mla-new` is the `\newunit`/`\newblockpunct`?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get better results using `@suppcollection` instead of `@incollection` for introductions

```
@suppcollection{Anker.2017b,
  author    = {Anker, Elizabeth S. and Meyler, Bernadette},
  pages     = {1--30},
  publisher = {Oxford UP},
  editor    = {Anker, Elizabeth S. and Meyler, Bernadette},
  booktitle = {New Directions in Law and Literature},
  title     = {Introduction},
  year      = {2017},
  location  = {New York},
}
```

Then you can use `title` instead of `titleaddon`.

`@suppcollection` is specifically for introductions and forewords.

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) says on pp. 9-10

> [`@suppbook`] Supplemental material in a `@book`. This type is closely related to the `@inbook` entry type. While `@inbook` is primarily intended for a part of a book with its own title (e.g., a single essay in a collection of essays by the same author), this type is provided for elements such as prefaces, introductions, forewords, afterwords, etc. which often have a generic title only. Style guides may require such items to be formatted differently from other `@inbook` items.
>
> [`@suppcollection`] Supplemental material in a `@collection`. This type is similar to `@suppbook` but related to the `@collection` entry type.

---

If that does not work for you, try

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:mla:title:alone}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{% suggested by StackExchange user Audrey
  \iffieldundef{labeltitle}
    {\printfield{titleaddon}}
    {\printfield[citetitle:\strfield{entrytype}]{labeltitle}}}%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{suppbook}\and\iffieldundef{title}}%
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield[mla:capital]{entrysubtype}}}%
    {}}
```

This prints the `titleaddon` if no `labeltitle` is present.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot, moewe. I've never heard of suppbook / suppcollection, but that works just fine, therefore I didn't mess with the code.

Comment: @1stluebbi `@suppbook` and `@suppcollection` are among the lesser known entry types. Nevertheless, they are something to keep in mind. Not all styles even take care of them, but `biblatex-mla` does quite a bit for the two. I think you can even do away with `\renewbibmacro*{cite:mla:title:internal}` if you use the `@supp...` types.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I deleted that \renewbibmacro* altogether and get all the desired results with @suppcollection. Thank you!